# Firebase Cloud Function not working as expected

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
exports.resetDailyFinalKills = functions.pubsub
    .schedule("58 16 * * *")
    .onRun(async (context) => {
      const players = firestore.collection("players");
      const goodtimes = await players.where("final_kills", ">", 0);
      goodtimes.forEach((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.ref.update({final_kills: 0});
      });
      return null;
    });
```

So I have this cloud function, and when I force run it nothing happens at all like it just says the function was successful but the final_kills field never gets updated. Can anyone help?
[image: Firestore]
Like I obviously have a player here which has a final_kills value that is greater than 0. So why doesn't this reset that back down to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note sure if I am missing something here but:*

You actually try to iterate over the `Query` object firebase creates when using the `where()` function on your collections. You actually never fetch the data from the database.

```js
const players = firestore.collection("players");
// fetch the objects from firestore
const goodtimes = await players.where("final_kills", ">", 0).get();

// iterate over the docs you receive
goodtimes.docs.forEach((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.ref.update({ final_kills: 0 });
});
```

Edit (regarding your comment):
Make sure you set your timezone properly after your `.schedule()` function:

```js
// timezone in my case
functions.pubsub.schedule('5 11 * * *').timeZone('Europe/Berlin')
```

Check [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) as a reference for your correct timezone.

Comment: Oh thank you and wait another thing I just realized is I mean this schedule time is whatever it is but I just realized it's probably not in my timezone right

Comment: yeah, check my edit above. hope it helps

Comment: Thanks yeah that helped. Could you also possibly help me figure out a solution to another question? Someone suggested to run the function every 10 minutes and query to check if the time is greater or less than the current time -  24 hours but this doesn't seem very efficient to me and I'd also not be exactly accurate and might end up changing the field a little late because the function only runs every 10 minutes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73220012/firebase-cloud-functions-how-to-make-some-data-reset-24-hours-after-it-was-added